# Bootstrap слайдер не работает

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, bootstrap

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>COBT</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="carousel slide" id="carouselExampleIndicators" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li class="active" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner slide-block">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="bg4.jpg" class="d-block w-80">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="bg1.jpg" class="d-block w-80">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="bg2.jpg" class="d-block w-80">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Prev</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё у Вас работает - просто стили и скрипты нужно правильные подключать:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>COBT</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="carousel slide" id="carouselExampleIndicators" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li class="active" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner slide-block">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/70729/ad3a1eab-8781-4543-aa28-71a29767194d/s1200" class="d-block img-fluid w-80">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/34158/826808ef-3f5d-4ae3-9b36-acf8d0f7f399/s1200" class="img-fluid d-block w-80">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/49816/203472834-elektrichka-lastochka-1461077903.51/s1200" class="img-fluid d-block w-80">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Prev</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body> 
    </html>
```